# How can I delete all text in a Word document using a macro?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to **delete all the text in a Word document leaving the images/embedded files**.

I know this should be easy, but can't a good example on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text is of Type wdSelectionNormal

So if you iterate throught all characters of document and delete the "characters" which are of type 2 when selected. It will do the trick.

This should not be really speedy, but it work.

This example responds to simple cases :

```
Dim curCharIndex As Integer
Dim charCount As Integer
curCharIndex = 1
charCount = ActiveDocument.Characters.Count

While curCharIndex <= charCount
    ActiveDocument.Characters(curCharIndex).Select
    If Selection.Type = wdSelectionNormal Then
        Selection.Delete
        charCount = charCount - 1
    Else
        'Skip it
        curCharIndex = curCharIndex + 1
    End If
Wend
```